# Unable to upload assets with git action

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to upload a binary with in git action using https://github.com/alexellis/upload-assets . Here is the snippet of where I call it.

```yaml
      - name: Prepare executables for uploading
        run: |
          mkdir executables
          # mv target/production/node-template executables/node-template
          mv target/debug/foo executables/foo

      - name: Upload node template executables to assets
        uses: alexellis/upload-assets@0.3.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ github.token }}
        with:
          asset_paths: '["executables/*"]'
```

Unfortunately , I get the error:

```bash
Run alexellis/upload-assets@0.3.0
Error: Not Found
```

I would appreciate any pointers on resolving this , as I can't understand why it wont pick up the variable

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a release before calling the GitHub action `alexellis/upload-assets@0.3.0`.

Here is some example using GitHub action [actions/create-release](https://github.com/actions/create-release)

```
      - name: Create release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@latest
        env: 
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.repo_token }}
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          release_name: Release ${{ github.ref }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false
```